# How to use npm package in nw.js without installing Node JS

Tags: node.js, npm, node-webkit, nw.js

I want to use this npm package(https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-ssh) in my nw.js application,
In my dev system installed node js and installed this package and successfully its working
, But while shipping this application I don't want to make a dependency to node js. Without installing the node js can nw.js use this package.

Any help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Gradle wrapper](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/gradle_wrapper.html) and the [Gradle Plugin for Node](https://github.com/node-gradle/gradle-node-plugin).

To avoid having to install gradle, I use [Spring Initializr](https://start.spring.io/) to create a simple project that has the gradle wrapper in it.  Then I'll just copy the `gradle` folder, the `gradlew` and `gradlew.bat`.  All that's left then is to create the `.gitignore` and `build.gradle` files.